# Unterschied zwischen Haus & Heim

Tags: english-to-german, difference, german-to-english, standard-german

was ist der Unterschied zwischen **Haus** & **Heim**? z.b. es ist ebenso wie **House** & **Home** am Englisch?

Im translate schreibt es:

> ENG zu DEU:
>
> I'am at home --> Ich bin zu Hause

Aber Sie kennen, dass **I am at house** eine richtige Englisches Grammatik ist nicht. So was muss ich **I am at home** sagen? *Ich bin Heim?*

Ich bin lvl B1.1

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haus#bedeutungen

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Heim#bedeutungen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer in English since you seem to be more proficient therein than in German.

There is a loose connection between "Haus" - "house" and "Heim" - "home", but it doesn't always apply as you've noticed. "Haus" is usually referring to a building, where "Heim" is referring to the place you call "home" (see also "Heimat"), as is in English.

But as always, there are exceptions. "Ich bin zu Hause" (also: "zuhause") is the correct translation for the phrase "I am at home".

More examples:

- "Eigenheim" is the *house* you own
- "mein Zuhause" is the place I call *home*
- "Haus und Hof verlieren" = "to lose everything".

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful!

Comment: In Österreich/Schweiz/Süddeutschland verbreitet gibt es noch "daheim": I'm at home => Ich bin daheim. Ich weiß nicht, wie weit das im Norden verstanden und verwendet wird

Comment: Stimmt und versteht man auch hier in "Südschweden" ^^.

Comment: Note "Haus und Hof" is a Stabreim (a form of poetry in ancient German using same start letters/sounds), and such are often used even when more or less redundant ("Haus" is the building, "Hof" is the whole estate).